# Functions in Micro-python

Tags: esp8266, micropython, esptool

i have a question about micro-python that how to make and call functions in micro-python or any other idea related to functions
my code throwing an error that **NameError: name 'my_func' isn't defined**

```
import time
from machine import Pin
led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
btn = Pin(4, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
while True:
    if not btn.value():
        my_func()
        while not btn():
            pass
        
def my_func():
    led(not led())
    time.sleep_ms(300)
```

Comment: Have you considered defining your function before you call it?

Answer (score 1):

Generaly, what I do following: Imports then Functions and after that- rest of the flow

Slightly modified your code to pass LED object for function

```
import time
from machine import Pin

def my_func(myLed):
    myLed.value(not myLed.value()) # invert boolean value
    time.sleep_ms(300)


led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
btn = Pin(4, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
while True:
    if not btn.value():
        my_func(led)
        while not btn():
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to import a function before it can be called.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).